# React/Redux and API data object

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

My app successfully gets API data and puts it to Redux state tree.

```
{  
   "coord":{  
      "lon":-0.13,
      "lat":51.51
   },
   "weather":[  
      {  
         "id":311,
         "main":"Drizzle",
         "description":"drizzle rain",
         "icon":"09d"
      },
      {  
         "id":501,
         "main":"Rain",
         "description":"moderate rain",
         "icon":"10d"
      }
   ],
   //-------- 
    //-------- 
    "id":2643741,
   "name":"London",
   "cod":200
}
```

`Props.data` has been passed to components but in reality I have an access only to the 
`first key`. For example `props.data.name`, `props.data.id` are accesiible. But `props.data.coord.lon` 
and `props.data.weather.map(---)`, are undefined.
Please, what's wrong with my understanding of using API dataset?

Component

```
export const DayItem = (props) => {
  return (<MuiThemeProvider>
                <Paper zDepth={2}>
                {props.data.coord.lon} // No way!
                {props.data.name} // OK!
                </Paper>
              </MuiThemeProvider>)}
```

Saga that gets data and dispatches an action. Puts data to Redux store.

```
function* getPosition() {
  const getCurrentPosition = () => new Promise(
    (res, rej) => navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(res, rej))

  // Gets user's current position assigned to const
  const pos = yield call(getCurrentPosition);
  const {latitude, longitude} = pos.coords;

  // Yields the forecast API by user coordinates
  const data = yield call(getForecastByCoords, latitude, longitude)

  // Yields user's local forecast to the reducer
  yield put({
    type: LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS,
    data
  });
}
```

And mapStateToProps

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return {
    chips: state.chipsReducer,
    data: state.dataReducer
  }
};
```

dataReducer

```
export const dataReducer = (state = {}, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS:
      return action.data;
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: I think it might help if you post the component that's trying to get this data, and the redux store/actions.

Comment: Also, the `mapStateToProps` function

Comment: Can we see `state.dataReducer`?

Comment: I guess, there is something wrong with my dataReducer. But I tried to save the whole API object then retrieve pieces of data.

Comment: Taking in account general recomendation on Redux by Dan Abramov: "The state should be serializable",
I tried to get ensured that recieved from weather API object is JSON-safe. 
And tried a pattern from Kyle Simpson:  `const data = yield JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result))`
before
`yield put({
    type: LOAD_DATA_SUCCESS,
    data
  })`

Regrettably, nothing changed. I can acces only the first key, e.g. `props.data.name` 
but `props.data.coord.lat` //undefined.
Please, what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eventually, I got the point.
The problem was in the difference of speed React rendering vs Data loading.
Loading is always behind rendering. So, the complete set of data had no existence.

Just conditional rendering made my day `{this.state.isLoading ? <div>Loading</div> : <DayItem {...this.props}/>}`

Answer (score -1):

you must use MapStateToProps, then use     componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps)

Something like this

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {


    return {

      data:state.toJS().yourReducer.data,

    }
```

then do next:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
if (nextProps.data) {
      if (nextProps.data.coord.lon != undefined) {
        this.setState({yourData:nextProps.data.coord.lon}
      }
}
```

Comment: why would the OP have to use `componentWillReceiveProps`?  And `toJS()` would only be used for `immutable.js` data.